# How to store all possible two characters from a string into the String array in java..?

Tags: java, arrays, string

How to store all possible two characters from a string into the String array in java..?
For example if I give the string "abcd". then I want to store all possible two characters (aa,ab,ac,ad,ba,bb,bc,bd,ca,cb,cc,cd,da,db,dc,dd) into string array..
How can I do this?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: @ravikumar Please review the answers to your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service, please show your efforts

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this and avoid duplicates is to iterate over the String and use a `Set` to store the results:

```
String input = "abcd";
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
for (int i=0; i < input.length()-1; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < input.length(); ++j) {
        String value = input.charAt(i) + "" + input.charAt(j);
        set.add(value);    // duplicates will not be added
    }
}

// convert the set to a String array
String[] array = set.toArray(new String[set.size()]);
```

Comment: `'a'` + `'a'` will be `130` ;) This won't produce `"aa"` or `"dd"`

Comment: I didn't down vote, but you still won't produce `"aa"` or `"dd"` but your code would be simpler if it did.

Comment: I tested the code, and, yes it does produce `"aa"` and `"dd"`.  Inserting an empty string (`""`) in between the characters forces a cast to string.

Comment: In that case, the code you tested doesn't match because `j=1` to start with so it `input.charAt(j)` can't be an `a` and `i < input.length()-1` so similarly can't be a `d`.

Comment: `j` should be initialized to `i`, not `i+1`.  Also, `i` should end at `input.length()`.  If you refer to the example in the OP, `"aa"` is a valid result of the input `"abcd"`

Comment: @mstbaum that's is what I thought but the OP appears to want permutations rather than combinations e.g. there is both `ba` and `ab`

Comment: @PeterLawrey right sorry I meant `j` should be initialized to 0. but `i` should still end one iteration later than how @TimBiegeleisen has it now.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8, you could do

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(twoCharCombinations("abcd"));
}

public static String twoCharCombinations(String s) {
    return IntStream.range(0, s.length()).boxed().flatMap(i ->
                    IntStream.range(0, s.length()).boxed().map(j ->
                            "" + s.charAt(i) + s.charAt(j))
                           ).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

prints

```
aa,ab,ac,ad,ba,bb,bc,bd,ca,cb,cc,cd,da,db,dc,dd
```

You can `.collect(Collectors.toList())` to create a List of String and from that a String[] instead.

Comment: @ChakerMallek hit and run downvotes without comments are like saying; I could have told you what you did wrong, but I can't be bothered.

Comment: Your answer seems to be perfect and up to date (java 8). I can guaruantee the last downvote came from one who doesn't even know what programming is.

Comment: +1 for correcting my mistakes (several times).  I truly think functional programming doesn't work well with Java.  That being said, I use Guava collections all the time, so I am something of a hypocrite.

Comment: @ChakerMallek I do get downvotes from people who don't like answers to questions which they think shouldn't be answered. i.e. because the question doesn't show enough effort in attempting a solution.